# Why is setscheduler not forcing need resched

Tags: linux, scheduling

I noticed that in Linux kernel 2.4 setscheduler doesn't force need_resched. Why is that? is it just some convention, or does that happens somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need_resched is invoked elsewhere in the system.

The scheduler is markedly different in modern 2.6 kernels, and by many accounts much better. I personally wouldn't dive too deep into 2.4 unless its for historical curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a known bug in 2.4,anyway, in the next tic all will be fine :)